# How to reset my game to its previous state when I am using HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, game-development

This is my ping pong game.

The game ends once the ball hits the left side three times.

I want a solution through which I can reset the game once the game ends and I can **start a new one**.

But I am finding it difficult to do maybe because the canvas behaves abnormally.
Any solution to this problem?

And also **after reset the mouseover thing stops working**.

- notice that I have used the same function for both game starts and game ends message box inside the html file **on click event**.

  ```js
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let canvasX = 0,
      canvasY = 0;

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 100;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 100;

  // Game logic
  let tick;
  let gameEnd = false;
  let mistakeCount = 0;
  let playerHeights = 150;
  let executed = false;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

  // canvas
  let cw = canvas.width;
  let ch = canvas.height;
  ctx.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, cw, ch);

  // player who is playing
  let playerPos = ch / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(10, playerPos, 10, playerHeights);

  // ball position
  let ballX = cw / 2,
      ballY = ch / 2,
      ballHorizontalDirection = true, //right side
      ballAngle = 5; // The amount of pixels the ball has to move upwards

  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  // computer player
  let computerPos = ch / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(cw - 20, computerPos, 10, playerHeights);

  function gameloop(buttonId) {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
          // e.clientX,e.clientY
          playerPos = e.clientY;
      });
      document.getElementById(buttonId).style.display = "none";
      let i = 0;
      draw();
  }

  function resetTheGame() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(tick);
      document.getElementById("gameover").style.display = "flex";
      executed = false;
      gameEnd = false;
      mistakeCount = 0;
      playerPos = ch / 2;
      ballX = cw / 2;
      ballY = ch / 2;
      ballHorizontalDirection = true; //right side
      ballAngle = 5;
      computerPos = ch / 2;
  }

  function checkForPlayerCollision() {
      if (ballX <= 25 && ballY < playerPos + playerHeights && ballY > playerPos) {
          ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
          let firstHalf = playerPos + playerHeights / 2;
          if (ballY > firstHalf + 20) {
              ballAngle = 5;
          } else if (ballY > firstHalf - 20 && ballY < firstHalf + 20) {
              ballAngle = 0;
          } else {
              ballAngle = -5;
          }
      }
      if (ballX >= cw - 20) {
          ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
      }
  }

  function selectBallPosition() {
      if (ballHorizontalDirection) {
          ballX += 5;
      } else {
          ballX -= 5;
      }
  }

  function gameEnds() {
      if (!executed) {
          if (ballX >= cw || ballX <= 5) {
              if (mistakeCount == 2) {
                  alert("Game End");
                  executed = true;
                  resetTheGame();
                  return true;
              }
              ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
              mistakeCount++;
              return false;
          }
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  function setPlayerPositions() {
      if (playerPos + playerHeights >= ch - 40 || playerPos <= 20) {
          playerPos = playerPos;
      }
      if (computerPos + playerHeights >= ch - 20 || computerPos <= 20) {
          computerPos = computerPos;
      }
  }

  function checkForTopBottomCollision() {
      if (ballY <= 10 || ballY >= ch - 20) {
          ballAngle = -1 * ballAngle;
      }
  }

  function draw() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(tick);
      ctx.clearRect(10, 10, cw, ch);

      // context
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, cw, ch);

      // player
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(10, playerPos, 10, playerHeights);
      ballY += ballAngle;

      // computer
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(cw - 20, ballY - 20, 10, playerHeights);

      // ball
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();

      // frame
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = "20";
      ctx.rect(0, 0, cw, ch);
      ctx.stroke();

      // dotted line in between
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = "1";
      ctx.setLineDash([20, 5]);
      ctx.moveTo(cw / 2, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(cw / 2, ch);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.setLineDash([]);
      ctx.closePath();

      // score board for player
      ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
      ctx.font = "100px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
      ctx.fillText("0", cw / 2 - 150, ch / 2 + 35);

      // score board for computer
      ctx.fillText(mistakeCount, cw / 2 + 100, ch / 2 + 35);

      if (!gameEnd) {
          tick = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
          selectBallPosition();
          setPlayerPositions();
          checkForPlayerCollision();
          checkForTopBottomCollision();
          gameEnd = gameEnds();
      }
  }
  ```

  ```css
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  }

  #gameover {
      display: none;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: rgba(247, 14, 14, 14, 0.7);
  }

  #start {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      line-height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: xx-large;
      background-color: rgba(14, 14, 247, 0.7);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="start" onclick="gameloop('start')">
          Click any where to continue
      </div>
      <div id="gameover" onclick="gameloop('gameover')">
          Game Over! <br> Click any where to continue
      </div>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: just a "code style" note. Please try to not using a combination of "in-line" event handlers (in html onclick) and in-code handlers. (your click handler should be in the JavaScript code. it just makes it easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is why I added the last line in bolted as note. I tried using click handler in javascript but it executes the function before the event occurs. I don't know why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I have solved this problem by my own.
Instead of using separate "gameover" div to display game over I can use the given code below.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let canvasX = 0,
    canvasY = 0;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 100;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 100;

// Game logic
let tick;
let gameEnd = false;
let mistakeCount = 0;
let playerHeights = 150;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

// canvas
let cw = canvas.width;
let ch = canvas.height;
ctx.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, cw, ch);

// player who is playing
let playerPos = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(10, playerPos, 10, playerHeights);

// ball position
let ballX = cw / 2,
    ballY = ch / 2,
    ballHorizontalDirection = true, //right side
    ballAngle = 5; // The amount of pixels the ball has to move upwards

ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// computer player
let computerPos = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(cw - 20, computerPos, 10, playerHeights);

function gameloop(buttonId) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        // e.clientX,e.clientY
        playerPos = e.clientY;
    });
    document.getElementById(buttonId).style.display = "none";
    let i = 0;
    draw();
}

function resetTheGame() {
    mistakeCount = 0;
    ballX = cw / 2;
    ballY = ch / 2;
    ballHorizontalDirection = true;
}

function checkForPlayerCollision() {
    if (ballX <= 25 && ballY < playerPos + playerHeights && ballY > playerPos) {
        ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
        let firstHalf = playerPos + playerHeights / 2;
        if (ballY > firstHalf + 20) {
            ballAngle = 5;
        } else if (ballY > firstHalf - 20 && ballY < firstHalf + 20) {
            ballAngle = 0;
        } else {
            ballAngle = -5;
        }
    }
    if (ballX >= cw - 20) {
        ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
    }
}

function selectBallPosition() {
    if (ballHorizontalDirection) {
        ballX += 5;
    } else {
        ballX -= 5;
    }
}

function gameEnds() {
    if (ballX >= cw || ballX <= 5) {
        if (mistakeCount == 2) {
            resetTheGame();
            return true;
        }
        ballHorizontalDirection = !ballHorizontalDirection;
        mistakeCount++;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

function setPlayerPositions() {
    if (playerPos + playerHeights >= ch - 40 || playerPos <= 20) {
        playerPos = playerPos;
    }
    if (computerPos + playerHeights >= ch - 20 || computerPos <= 20) {
        computerPos = computerPos;
    }
}

function checkForTopBottomCollision() {
    if (ballY <= 10 || ballY >= ch - 20) {
        ballAngle = -1 * ballAngle;
    }
}

function draw() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(tick);
    ctx.clearRect(10, 10, cw, ch);

    // context
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, cw, ch);

    // player
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(10, playerPos, 10, playerHeights);
    ballY += ballAngle;

    // computer
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(cw - 20, ballY - 20, 10, playerHeights);

    // ball
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // frame
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "20";
    ctx.rect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.stroke();

    // dotted line in between
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "1";
    ctx.setLineDash([20, 5]);
    ctx.moveTo(cw / 2, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(cw / 2, ch);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.setLineDash([]);
    ctx.closePath();

    // score board for player
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.font = "100px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText("0", cw / 2 - 150, ch / 2 + 35);

    // score board for computer
    ctx.fillText(mistakeCount, cw / 2 + 100, ch / 2 + 35);

    if (!gameEnd) {
        tick = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        selectBallPosition();
        setPlayerPositions();
        checkForPlayerCollision();
        checkForTopBottomCollision();
        gameEnd = gameEnds();
    } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(tick);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        // context
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
        ctx.font = "50px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText("You Lose!", cw / 4, ch / 2);
        ctx.fillText("Click to continue", cw / 4, ch / 2 + 100);

        canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
            tick = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            gameEnd = false;
            canvas.removeEventListener("click");
        });
    }
}
```

The changes made to the code from the initial code are

```
function resetTheGame() {
    mistakeCount = 0;
    ballX = cw / 2;
    ballY = ch / 2;
    ballHorizontalDirection = true;
}
```

and added an else loop here

```
if (!gameEnd) {
        tick = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        selectBallPosition();
        setPlayerPositions();
        checkForPlayerCollision();
        checkForTopBottomCollision();
        gameEnd = gameEnds();
    } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(tick);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        // context
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
        ctx.font = "50px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText("You Lose!", cw / 4, ch / 2);
        ctx.fillText("Click to continue", cw / 4, ch / 2 + 100);

        canvas.addEventListener("click", () => {
            tick = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            gameEnd = false;
            canvas.removeEventListener("click");
        });
    }
```